# Get a list of all author IDs for a given given university with pybliometrics

Tags: scopus, pybliometrics

I am trying to get the complete list of author IDs  associated with a given University.

I tried to do it from the Scopus web page but my request exceeded the allowed quota.

Any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the [AuthorSearch](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/AuthorSearch.html) class for that. Scopus hides the documentation for this API [here](https://dev.elsevier.com/sc_author_search_tips.html), so it's a bit tricky to find all the allowed fields.

What you want is the key "AF-ID":

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AuthorSearch

q = "AF-ID(60105007)"
s = AuthorSearch(q)
print(s)
```

The results are in `s.authors`.

Comment: Thanks your for your help, it works!! however, when I tried to retrieve more than the limited quota I got this message "pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus400Error" Is there any way to overcome this? in my case I cannot find parameters for authors Id to limit my search

Comment: Usually this error points at broken queries. If you're sure this is not the case, you  can restrict the query to author IDs of specific ranges, e.g. `AF-ID(60105007) AND AU-ID(*0)` where you replace the last digit iteratively until you covered all digits